# $any() type cast function in Angular template

Tags: angular

How to use the **$any()** type cast function in Angular template?

In angular documentation-
https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck#disabling-type-checking-using-any
some description and examples have been given but still, it is not clear.

There one example is given like this-

```
<p>The item's undeclared best by date is: {{$any(item).bestByDate}}</p>
```

Comment: Why do you need to cast? Can't you simply access it by `{{item.bestByDate}}`?

Comment: This is an example given in Angular documentation. I just want to know the implementation of the type cast function in Angular template.

Comment: Check this article :https://medium.com/@a.yurich.zuev/type-checking-templates-in-angular-viewengine-and-ivy-77f8536359f5 written by @user:5485167

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Simply wrap a variable with `$any()`. No additional code required.

component.ts

```ts
export class AppComponent {
  val = { name: 'foobar' }
}
```

component.html

```html
<p>
  {{ $any(val).name }}
</p>
```

stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qivjym

Comment: Hi zmag, what is the use of `$any()` here, instead we can simply access it by `{{val.name}}`

Comment: @Nitish it states right in the documentation : `Sometimes a binding expression triggers a type error during AOT compilation and it is not possible or difficult to fully specify the type.`

Comment: @Nitish As documented, sometimes there's a type error when AOT Compiling which is hard to resolve. Then you can specify the type is `any`, like in ts `val: any`

Comment: what the purpose of using $any(),how it prevent from compilition errors?

Answer (score 9):

The example given by the accepted answer does not show the real reason behind `$any`

```html
<p> {{obj.prop1}}</p>
<!--
This will throw an error without $any() because newProp is not part of typeof obj.  
<p> {{obj.newProp}}</p>
-->
<p> {{$any(obj).newProp}}</p>
```

*ts

```ts
obj = { prop1: 'hehe'};

ngOnInit() {
  (this.obj as any).newProp = 'lol';
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-aofufm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html