# Angular Template Reference Object with multiple types

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an object bound to the template. This object has two types.

```
const config: IDialogConfig | IDialogConfig[];
```

My template looks something like this.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="isArray(config); else singleMessage">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let message of config">
        <p [fieldId]="message.fieldKey" class="display-4 confirm-msg"></p>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #singleMessage>
    <p [fieldKey]="config.fieldKey" class="display-4 confirm-msg"></p>
</ng-template>
```

Now, with this kind of setup, I am getting an error inside the `#singleMessage` template

> Property 'fieldID' does not exist on type 'IDialogMessage[]'

Is there anyway I can make this setup works? As much as possible I do not want to use an `any` type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep the config type as is it, but within the template, you can use `$any()` method to handle this error:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="isArray(config); else singleMessage">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let message of config">
        <p [fieldId]="message.fieldKey" class="display-4 confirm-msg"></p>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #singleMessage>
    <p [fieldKey]="$any(config).fieldKey" class="display-4 confirm-msg"></p>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: I tried this approach, yet I am still getting the error.

Comment: Oh. I thick I should encapsulate the main object only, and don't include the property. I'll update your answer. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56880979/2637261)

Answer (score 2):

Since we can't use as operator in template, it would be difficult to convert types in template, one way that I can think of is:

Have this code in your component:

```
  asDailogConfig(value) : IDialogConfig { return value; }
```

and then in your template:

```
<p [fieldKey]="(asDailogConfig(config)).fieldKey" class="display-4 confirm-msg"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) e.g. `configArr` of type `IDialogConfig[]`:

```
const config: IDialogConfig | IDialogConfig[]

get configArr(): IDialogConfig[] {
  return [this.config ?? []].flat()
}
```

And then in the view:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let message of configArr">
  <p [fieldId]="message.fieldKey" class="display-4 confirm-msg"></p>
</ng-container>
```

- Check working example [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8s4fgy?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: This is an interesting approach. I'll try this one.